# Write a function which takes parameters and with them generates a new function

Tags: python, function

For starters, let's set up what kind of function is needed, a cubic represented as a function:

```
def solve(x):
    return 5*x*x*x + 4*x*x + 3*x + 2
```

This function would then be used as part of another function to solve this cubic where values would be substituted for x to eventually find the correct value. Simple enough.

However, I am now given the prompt where I need to grab numbers that will serve as coefficients in this function, these are stored in a list named termsList. With this list, I grab the numbers and need to use a function named cubic() and am told that the only parameters used in cubic() are the terms I will be using for this function, while also having cubic() generate a function on its own, solve(). It's difficult to describe but based on my understanding of the instructions the result should be something vaguely similar to this:

```
def cubic(a, b, c, d):
    def solve(x):
        return float(a)*x*x*x, float(b)*x*x, float(c)*x, float(d)

solve1= cubic(termsList[0], termsList[1], termsList[2], termsList[3])

solving(solve(x))
```

All of my attempts to make this work have failed and I'm not sure where to go from this. The only things that cannot change at all are:

1. The result of using cubic() must be stored in variable solve1.
2. The function named solve() must be created as a result of running cubic()
3. The only 4 acceptable parameters for cubic() are the 4 values that will be used to make the function.
4. The resulting function named solve() must be runnable in a separate function after running cubic() as shown above.

I've omitted other parts of the code for simplicity's sake but that's the situation I'm in. All other code, including the function that will be using solve() later, has been tested to work. I'm really and truly stumped. No libraries can be used.

Comment: your code is almost correct, you just forgot to `return solve` from `cubic`. Also the `cubic` call could be simply `cubic(*termsList)`

Comment: @gog I tried                                                                                                                
 `def makePoly(a, b, c, d):
    def solve(x):
        return float(a)*x*x*x, float(b)*x*x, float(c)*x, float(d)
    return solve`                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                    
  and got an error "NameError: name 'solve' is not defined"

Comment: yes, you called it solve1, not solve. So you need to pass solve1 to solving. "solve" was just the name it has, as a local function, inside "cubic". It is exactly like for variables. If you define a local variable inside a function, and return it ``def afunction(): x=12; return x``, and then affect the result of that function to another variable, and print it, like this ``y=afunction(); print(y)``. You would not call ``print(x)``, would you? x is just the name of a local variable inside ``afunction``. It is y in which you store that value in the global context.

Comment: So, no difference here. It is the same for functions. "solve" is just the name you locally gave to your function inside "cubic". But outside cubic, what matters is in which variable you stored it. And you stored in into "solve1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your naming convention is odd, let's use more descriptive names:

```
def make_cubic(a, b, c, d):
    def func(x):
        return float(a)*x*x*x + float(b)*x*x + float(c)*x + float(d)
    return func

cubic = make_cubic(*termsList)

whatever(cubic(x))
```